how to reference to the range of sheets using regex
i have growing numbers of sheets. in last sheet i want to sum everything from first to prelast.
Is there way to get range of sheets like in python manner - list slicing:
SHEETS[:-2]
or by name matching:
"myname.*"
but without vba

There is no regex support for this kind of operation.
What you're looking for is a 3D reference.
It relies on:
a) the order of the sheets
b) the name of the first sheet you want to sum from
c) the name of the last sheet you want to sum from
So, if your first sheet is called 'Monday' and your second-to-last sheet is called 'Sunday', and you have a number in cell B2 in each of those sheets and every sheet between them, then this formula will return the sum of those values:
=SUM(Monday:Sunday!B2)

You can read more here.
From that page:

